# Excel form with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was given this Excel VBA form to fix. As soon as I open it, it jumps to the form and the tool bar and all menu buttons disappear. I need to access the VBA code behind the form to fix it(atleast try). How do I get to the guts of this form. I have passwords but do not know where to enter them. Thanks in advance.

I click the sheet and a dialog box pops up:

"The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected Sheet. To make changes, click Unprotect Sheet in the Review tab(you might need a password)."

The problem is, I cannot see the Review Tab or any other tab. Nothing.

Comment: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/stop-running-open-excel-spreadsheets-77491.html

Comment: You might also be able to use `Ctrl+Pause` to break operation, then you can click **Debug**.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file without activating VBA. Just open Excel, and then, in Recent Workbooks, press SHIFT and the open the Workbook. That way, the macros should not activate, and you can check the code.

Or just move the Workbook to a non trusted root, and open it.